# How to convert a file of format tar.gz to tar.bz2?

Tags: linux, compression, tar, gzip, bzip2

Like the title says, how do I do this conversion from the Linux console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine the two commands as following:

```
gunzip < file.gz | bzip2 > file.bz2
```

This will start two processes in parallel, `gunzip` reading the `file.gz` file and outputting the non-compressed stream to `bizp2` to re-compress it into `file.bz2`.

This process does not create intermediate files, you'll need to remove the `file.gz` afterwards (`rm file.gz`).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Mac: `No such file or directory` for the new archive.